# Форма WinForms, открытая через Show, после закрытия уничтожается

Tags: c#, winforms

```
// создали форму
Form f = new Form();

// на клик по кнопку отобразили её
f.Show();
// потом кликнули ещё раз, и "доступ к ликвидированному объекту невозможен".
```

Я знаю, это особенность реализации, но мне она чрезвычайно не нравится. Подскажите, можно ли каким-то способом (пусть даже через рефлексию) запретить высвобождение ресурсов при закрытии формы? (ShowDialog не подходит)

Comment: Сохраняйте во внешнем списке ссылки на создаваемые формы и все будет хорошо.

Comment: Ну неужели бы я до этого не додумался? Это особенность реализации - уничтожение при закрытии, и её надо обойти.

Comment: Вы опустили важные детали  в своем вопросе, поэтому вполне возможно предположить, что на вопрос "...Ну неужели бы я до этого не додумался? ..." - ответ будет - "да " :). Про перегрузку Close() и метод Hide() Вам уже написали. Пока по той информации, которую Вы дали - ничего другого предложить, ИМХО, нельзя.

Comment: Перегрузку Close()? Мне такого не писали. Кроме того, по новым условиям задачи, нельзя наследовать Form, только работать с созданным экземпляром.

Answer (score 5):

Напишите обработчик для Form.Closing Event

```
System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e


// Отменяет закрытие формы
e.Cancel = true;
```

и можете спокойно сделать

```
 ((Control)sender).Hide();
```

[прочитать можно тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.close?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Это вариант, соглашусь, я его проверял. Только мне нельзя блокировать вызов обработчика FormClosed.

Comment: @Antinet Собственно для каких целей вам нужно такое странное поведение? Я более чем уверен, что вы идете не тем путем. Если нужно закрыть форму и не освобождать ресурсы этой формы - используйте метод `Hide()` и напишите обработчик события `VisibleChanged`, где будет логика, которая описана у вас в `FormClosed`. Либо используйте предложенный выше вариант. Либо используйте `ShowDialog()`

Comment: Для собственной среды программирования с нестандартным поведением. Скорее всего, этот метод действительно применим, если из FormClosing вызвать FormClosed.